# Does the Messaging.InboundEmailHandler class handle multiple mails parallelly or serially?

Tags: apex

I have an apex class that implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler class for handling emails received by an email service address. Then, the mails are handled by handleInboundEmail() function where a custom object record is created and if there's an error during the proccessing, we send an error report email. We usually get multiple mails which try to create the same custom object records. And to avoid that we first check if a similar record already exists. If it does we don't create any new record and we also don't send any error report email.

Now the issue I have sometimes is that when the function first checks if similar record exists, it doesn't find any record but when it tries to insert a new record, an error is thrown stating that a duplicate record already exists(I've added a unique key field in the custom object) and an error report mail is sent(which is a false alarm as we already have the desired record from the previous mail processing).

I think this is being caused because the multiple mails are being processed parallelly and when the dml operation is in process while processing the first mail, and the thread processing the second mail can't find the record and will move forward with carrying out the DML operation which won't be successful as the thread processing the first mail will already have inserted the record.

Comment: What do you mean by making it run "synchronously" exactly? Running something synchronously implies a user has to wait for a process to complete. Obviously, when an e-mail is sent to a service, it can't wait. Can you be a bit more specific about your problem?

Comment: I suspect what you mean is "in parallel" versus "in serial". Is that the distinction you're aiming at?

Comment: @DanJones What I was meaning to say is that I wanted the second mail to be processed only after the first mail is done the processing.

Comment: @DavidReed Yes I meant to ask if the next mail is processed only after the current mail is processed completely and all the DML operations in the functions are completed or the next mail could be processed while the current mail is being processed and some DML operation is in progress.